# Why am I getting Test Failed: EOF when reading line

Tags: python

[image]I'm passing my code through an auto-grader and I keep getting the error EOF while reading a line.

The error looks like this:

```
Test on frequent_character  most_frequent function
Please enter a string: Test Failed: EOF when reading a line
```

And this is my code:

```
def most_frequent(s):
    frequency = [0]*26
    for letter in s:
        letter = letter.upper()
        if letter.isupper():
            frequency[ord(letter)-ord('A')] += 1
    max_index = frequency.index(max(frequency))
    return chr(max_index+ ord('a'))



def main():
    s = input('Please enter a string: ')
    print('The most frequenct letter is:',most_frequent(s))

main()
```

But my code runs just fine in the console.

Comment: Show us the full error message.

Comment: That is the full error message in the autograder

Comment: Please share with us the full error message. Also as you assigned `letter` to `letter.upper()`, then `if letter.isupper()` is always `True` and it is not necessary in my opinion and you can make your code shorter. You can change it to `if letter`

Comment: You may run different Python version in console than autograder. Check them.

Comment: But your code runs fine locally?

Comment: It does run fine

Comment: You do not have any objects called `frequent_character`. Are you sure you have copied the exact full message instead of writing error message on your own? Because the code works fine for me too